# 'Always Trust' wifi network not working

Tags: macos, network, wifi, security, certificate

This is more of an annoyance than anything...I have a MacBook Pro (latest Retina 15") and a Mac mini (latest model) both running Mac OS 10.8.4 and whenever I connect to my company's wifi network, I get prompted with a 'Verify Certficate' warning message. is there a way to permanently trust the newtork to avoid that warning?  There's an option to show the certificate which prompts with checkbox to 'always trust' and I have it selected, but whenever I connect I get the same message.   Is there something that I can do to avoid the warning message?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, one of two things is likely happening.

Here's what's supposed to happen, your IT department should package the certificates you need to "trust" their servers and networks and they should provide them and hopefully not change the certificates every few weeks or months. Better, they could pay for a real certificate that's signed by a trusted broker and your Mac would just know it was a valid certificate and not just something the IT department self-signed.

Your Mac should take the certificate needed and enter it into your keychain when you tell it to "always trust" the certificate, but that isn't working as well.

So - you could troubleshoot your keychain (start with the help menu in keychain access program) or learn more about how that works. You could ask IT to point you to the actual certificates and learn how to store them in your keychain or the system keychain. You'll want to run the **Certificate Assistant** from Keychain Access if you choose to store the certs locally since it will help you know if you have a good chain of trust and to debug things, since this usually takes several tries if you're not in the habit of installing custom certs into OS X.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Just want to be clear on what I need to ask of my IT as they're not the most receptive to mac related questions...I can see that there is a cert added to my keychain. I can also see that Keychain Access states the 'This certificate is marked as trusted for this account'.  

You're saying that I should ask them for the location of the actual certificates or for them to send me/allow me to download them so that I can add them as custom certs to my login keychains?

Comment: I get it - I put that in for the general case. In your case, you can pull the certs from the network and don't need to involve IT at all.